# What is the word for a new built property?

Tags: single-word-requests

My native language is Swedish. And I work as a webdeveloper. And at the moment I am working on a real estate website written in English.

So I would like to know,

> what is the best word to use when describing a building that was just
>   finished built, or is not finished yet but can still be bought right
>   now?

Should I use "New Construction" (Google translate suggestion) or is there a better word to use, that describe this? I would like to know the prefered word in bouth US and Britian

Comment: "New construction" sounds fine to my American ears, though I'm not familiar enough with real estate to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your input! :) Will waith and see if any other American answers  :)

Comment: I'd warn against "New Construction," as it might be an industry-specific term that could cause legal problems (Is "New Construction" construction completed within the last year? Two years? Never lived in?), at least in the US. You might check with a US-based Realty forum (or just call up a Realtor). Also, because the US is so weird, a term in one state might mean something entirely different in another.

Comment: Good point! Will do  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Britain a newly built house is known as a [*New-build*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=Define+new+build&oq=Define+new+build&gs_l=tablet-gws.12..0l2.2292.8408.0.9111.17.14.0.3.3.0.301.1913.3j8j1j1.13.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..2.15.1845.0.kObonnQSgTM).

You will see this term in advertising from Estate Agents and service industries such as plumbers.

Comment: What about US? Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Phorio Standards](http://standards.phorio.com), a site dedicated to understanding the terminology of building, architecture and real estate. It has definitions of more than 3,000 terms, each of which is translated into over 40 languages.

I'm American, and I think [completion](http://standards.phorio.com/?t=definition&code=4028829641) might be a good choice. It is defined as follows:

> Completion:
> A structure is basically finished on the outside, and at least partly ready for use.
>
> A structure is complete when the exterior is basically complete, with no major details remaining in its construction, and it is at least partly ready for its intended use. Fit-out of interior spaces may continue for any length of time after completion; it is not necessary for spaces inside to be occupied, as long as they are ready for hand-over to the occupant(s) without major structural work remaining.

Answer (score 0):

U.S.: newly built, new construction, or (my favorite) brand-new.